# What is the cause of this error:Exception during processing: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

What is the cause of this error:Exception during processing: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Comment: your using a native library and it can't find a fucntion. if your writting your own native lib then check that your functions are the same in C and java, if your using somebody elses check that your linking the lib correctly

Answer (score 4):

This is thrown if a `native` method is invoked, but the library that is being called cannot be located by the VM.  You should be able to find out which library is missing from the text on the line of the exception.  Ensure that library in question in either in your PATH, or add it to the library path in your commandline params for your app.  You can do this by specifying `-Djava.library.path=MY_LIB_PATH`  where `MY_LIB_PATH` is the path where your library lives.

Answer (score 1):

As Akf said your calling a native method that it can't find, can you put the exception stack and, if you know what it is, the code that crashes

you should have something like System.loadLibrary("mylib"); in your code
and some native methods

that where you'll find the source of your errors,

now why this occurs can be several things. some of the classical

-you don't have the lib.so with your project
-you moved/changed the packages of a project you imported
-you change the name of a native function

hope this helps